# AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed"

Tags: python, django

I'm using a CustomUser in my model. This is the User Manager.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, is_staff=False, is_superuser=False, is_active=False,
                    is_bot=False, is_mobile_verified=False, is_online=True, is_logged_in=True):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.info("REGULAR user created!")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email is required')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Username is required.')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, is_staff=is_staff, is_superuser=is_superuser,
                          is_active=is_active, is_bot=is_bot, is_mobile_verified=is_mobile_verified,
                          is_online=is_online, is_logged_in=is_logged_in)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.info("SUPER user created!")
        return self.create_user(email, username, password=password, is_staff=True, is_superuser=True, is_active=True,
                                is_bot=False, is_mobile_verified=False, is_online=True, is_logged_in=True)
```

This is my definition of the custom user model.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_mobile_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_logged_in = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_bot = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    #objects = UserManager()

    get_user_model().objects.create_user(...)
```

If I uncomment the line `objects = UserManager()` then I can run the server but the super users created from the admin backend can't log in.
If I use `get_user_model()` the code breaks and I get the following error

```
 "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'bouncer.User' that has not been installed
```

But in my settings.py I've define auth user model

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'bouncer.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you manage to get this working?  after upgrading to 2.1.4 from 2.0.6, I am getting this error and my setup is identical to yours.

Comment: @Ray nope I couldn't. I manually moved the project ....imagine!

Comment: Could you post your `INSTALLED_APPS` from settings.py? It could be that the import is failing or the import order needs to change.

Comment: Are you calling `get_user_model().objects.create_user(...)` within your custom user model??

Comment: Am I misreading this: why are you calling "create_user" in your `User` class definition?

Comment: I had this error message while trying to "makemigrations" for the AUTH_USER_MODEL. The reason was that inside same application with AUTH_USER_MODEL was a second model with use of get_user_model(). It was neccessary to comment out the 2nd model and make "makemigrations" in two steps.

Answer (score 15):

For anyone reading this in 2020, I suspect the problem is dependency related. I ran into the same error as OP.

**Your first two checks should be:**

1 - Is the app in the `installed apps` list in your `settings.py`?

2 - Is the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app_name_from_apps_py.model_name"` set in `settings.py`?

This was as far as most of the other responses I read go.

What I didn't realise on reading the docs is that to use `get_user_model()` you need to have established your model first. Of course, right?!

So above, where OP is using `get_user_model()`, they are creating a circular dependency. 
**You cannot use `get_user_model()` within the class that creates this model.**

Answer (score 5):

That error looks like `bouncer` isn't in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

So to clarify, you have to have

- `bouncer/models.py` that contains the `User` model (or `models/__init__.py` which imports the model from another file)
- `'bouncer'` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in the settings
- `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'bouncer.User'` (as you do).

Comment: Yes bouncer is in the installed apps list.

Comment: is `bouncer` before your app in the installed apps list?  From the question it's not totally obvious when you are actually calling `get_user_model`, but if it is happening while django is loading your app then `bouncer` would have to be loaded first.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I accidentally pasted in `Meta` class of my custom user the attribute `abstract = True`. So it raises this error.

Answer (score 3):

For me this was because I had `myapp/models/__init__.py` and I tried putting the custom `User` model definition in `myapp/models/user.py`, and setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL = myapp.User`. Moving the custom `User` model definition into `myapp/models/__init__.py` fixed it. I was unable to import it in `__init__.py`; I had to move the definition there.

Comment: wow, tried many things, this is the one that worked for me! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you register your model in admin.py and not in models.py

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.register(YourUser, UserAdmin)
```

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Never put custom user model and additional models containing links to user model in one models.py file in one app. This can be a matter of that error.

Bad idea leading to that error:

```
# customUserModel/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.conf import settings

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

This is a good idea:

```
# customUserModel/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

# additionalUserProfile/models.py
from django.conf import settings
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=25)

#settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customUserModel.User'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try shifting the position of the bouncer app in your `INSTALLED APPS`, this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason the import `from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend` caused this problem. I suspect that BaseBackend tries to use the user model, but can't because it's defined further down the file. However if you define your model BEFORE that import then it'll work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I'm aware this is an old question but I struggled with this issue for two days before finding my mistake, which was failing to follow the models organization [in the Django Models docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package).

I would have just commented on [@5fec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583763/5fec)'s answer, but I don't have the reputation yet.  My answer is similar to his, except importing the model in `models/__init__.py` worked for me.  I had neglected the `__init__.py` file entirely.

If you have the `AUTH_USER_MODEL = <app_name>.<user_model>` correctly written, and you have your `'<app_name>'`, in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list, but you're still getting this error, it's possible that your `<custom_user>` model (e.g. `User`) is in the wrong place.

It needs to be defined in either:

- `<app_name>.models.py`

OR

- `<app_name>/models/<arbitrary_name>.py` **AND** there is an `<app_name>/models/__init__.py` that contains the line `from .<arbitrary_name> import <custom_user>`

Answer (score -2):

try importing `from django.db import models` only *after* importing `from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser`